# Flatten BQ Logs tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out how to flatten the bigquery log tables (logs.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_20160404 etc) so that i can basically see all completed jobs for any given destination table.

I ideally just want something like the below to show me all the entries for jobs that touched the table [dataset_xyz.table_abc] and then i can figure out how to make sense of some fields being populated based on type of job etc.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  [logs.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_20160404]
where
  (
  protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.destinationTable.datasetId='dataset_xyz'
  and
  protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.destinationTable.tableId='table_abc'
  )
  or
  (
  protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.tableCopy.destinationTable.datasetId='dataset_xyz'
  and
  protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.tableCopy.destinationTable.tableId='table_abc'
  )
  or
  (
  protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.datasetId='dataset_xyz'
  and
  protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.tableId='table_abc'
  )
```

I was trying to do lots of nested flattens but i could not really figure it out tbh as find the log structure a bit complex.

I basically want to be able to query the log exports to say "show me everything that had anything to do with editing table [dataset_xyz.table_abc]" so i guess mainly load, tableCopy, and query jobs that either appended or overwrote any data in table [dataset_xyz.table_abc].

The only next thing i can think of it to literally pick apart the table along its nested records and then somehow join them all back together separately but that seems like a crazy idea. I'm sure there is a way to flatten it repeatedly but i just cant figure out how to flatten such a complicated structure. Even if i could just flatten everything under protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.* so i could do

```
select protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.* from flatten(...
```

Or maybe there is a much easier way to go about this that i'm missing?

p.s. i think this could be a good example for the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs) as i'd imagine is a common enough thing people want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

SELECT protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobName.jobId
FROM [audit_logs.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_20160406] 
omit record if ( sum(

(protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.destinationTable.tableId = 'table' and
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.destinationTable.datasetId = 'ds'
)
or 
(
  protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.datasetId = 'ds' AND
  protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.tableId = 'table'

)
) = 0)